# Images/media not loading with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, media-library

I am developing a wordpress website and am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to make a slideshow of images that will be displayed in a fixed position on the page. I have installed the plugin and created the custom field and everything is working fine, until when I have to upload the images: The media library does not load any images, and when I upload new ones it displays an error stating "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

I have tried making other custom fields with text and they work as expected, it is only the media uploading that seems to be the problem.

Any answers, suggestions, tips or tricks highly appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend checking the image upload in general without custom fields. Maybe there is an issue.

Comment: there can be a permission issue with the upload folder. will you please check the permission of upload folder is set to "755"

Comment: Thank you for the answers!
I can upload images without custom fields without any problems.

How can I check the permission? The website is currently on my localhost and I tried changing the permission of the folders wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes to read&write instead of read only, but the problem remains.

Comment: I found out how to check the permission and it is 755.